# Extract data from a list to multiple rows in a CSV file (Python3)

Tags: python, csv

I'm totally new to python (using python 3.6). Just having troubles in extracting the information from a list in Python to a csv file. I have the following list containing 108 strings:

```
lines = [('10-k','2','3','4','10-k','6','7','8','10-K','10','11',...,'108']
```

such that every four strings there is a '10-k' word. I am trying to extract this list in a csv file with the following code:

```
with open ('extracted.csv', 'w') as out_file:
wr = csv.writer(out_file)
wr.writerow(["file_form", "n1", "n2", "n3"])  # Headlines
wr.writerow(lines)
```

The 'extracted.csv' file generates two rows: a) top row with the headlines (ok fine) and b) a second row with each string in a different column (i.e. row 2 has as many columns as number of strings, that is, 108 columns). I would like my extracted.csv file to generate a new row at each '10-k' string. In the end, there would be 27 rows x 4 columns per row = 108 strings.
I have been trying to generate a matrix of 27x4 out of my long string (using arrays), but couldn't quite figure it out.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Split the variable and loop that new variable :)

Comment: Can you guarantee `10-k` appears every 4 items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can guarantee that your data is consistent (`10-k` consistently appears every 4 elements), you can loop through `lines` and extract chunks of size 4. So, this should work:

```
with open ('extracted.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    wr = csv.writer(out_file)
    wr.writerow(["file_form", "n1", "n2", "n3"])  # Headlines
    for i in range(0, len(lines), 4):
        wr.writerow(lines[i : i + 4])
```

Comment: Awesome COLDSPEED! love it, simple and efficient. spent quite a long time at this one...

Comment: @martins Glad I could help :>

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
lines = [('10-k','2','3','4','10-k','6','7','8')][0]

rows = [lines[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(lines), 4)]
```